# How to render data object from JSON in bootstrap columns in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I render objects from `GET` call to my html and wrap the `data` in bootstrap `col-*`

Trying to rendering it to something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="./assets/imgs/products/coke-medium.png" alt="...">
     <div class="caption">
        <p>Coke 500ml</p>
        <p>
          <b>£1.99</b>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button" onclick="addItem()">Add</a>
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is my `GET` function, however in the foreach it's only giving me the last item name. Also is there a better way of doing this than what I'm trying to do below?

```
 function getDrinks() {
    $.get('./assets/products.json')
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.drinks);
            var drinks  = data.drinks;

            for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
                var element = drinks[i];
                $('#drink_list').html('<div class="col-sm-4">' + element.name + '</div>');
            }
        })
    }
```

JSON sample --

```
{
 "drinks":[
    {
        "name": "Coke",
        "liter": "500ml",
        "image": "/products/coke-medium.png"
    },
}
```

Comment: What is your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `html` replace the content of `drink_list`. you need to use `append` http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
     var element = drinks[i];
     $('#drink_list').append('<div class="col-sm-4">' + element.name + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: But is this an efficient way of rendering a repeatable data or is there better way? Just thought writing `html` layout in JS is not a good idea